# Unable to download .zip from Github: github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com’s server IP address could not be found

Tags: github, download, dns

I try to download https://github.com/taniman/profit-trailer/releases/download/2.3.3/ProfitTrailer-2.3.3.zip and https://github.com/PTMagicians/PTMagic/releases/download/2.2.2/PTM.2.2.2.zip.. but I get an error (screenshot) Looks like some DNS error? Please advice, ty.

[image: error loading site]

NSLOOKUP Results (as you can see, it resolves google.com and amazonaws.com just fine..)

```
        > github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com
    Server:  router.domain_not_set.invalid
    Address:  192.168.1.254

    DNS request timed out.
        timeout was 2 seconds.
    DNS request timed out.
        timeout was 2 seconds.
    *** Request to router.domain_not_set.invalid timed-out
    > google.com
    Server:  router.domain_not_set.invalid
    Address:  192.168.1.254

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:    google.com
    Addresses:  2a00:1450:400e:80c::200e
              172.217.168.206

> amazonaws.com
Server:  router.domain_not_set.invalid
Address:  192.168.1.254

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    amazonaws.com
Addresses:  72.21.210.29
          207.171.166.22
          72.21.206.80
```

Comment: It looks like a temporary DNS server problem. I can successfully download these 2 files here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed. Turned out to be a temporary DNS glitch.